# How to remove double quote in broken nested json values?

Tags: javascript

Am stuck with applying replace() with regex for broken nested json value. For example, i want to remove doublequote for origin value below.

How to change from this:

```
{
 "type" : "fruitList",
 "data" : [{
   "fruitName" : "test",
   "origin" : "[{"states" : "USA"}]"
 }]
}
```

To this:

```
{
 "type" : "fruitList",
 "data" : [{
   "fruitName" : "test",
   "origin" : [{"states" : "USA"}]
 }]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use 2 `replace` without RegEx:

```
jsonstring.replace('"[', "[").replace(']"', "]")
```

Or if you just want to use a single `replace` with RegEx:

```
jsonstring.replace(/("\[|\]")/g, match => {
   return match === '"[' ? "[" : "]"
})
```

Comment: 2nd option helped me a lot in my case as I need to replace it globally. 1st option only replace data[0].origin[0] only, not in data[1].origin[0] and so on if any.